# OpenJPA check column length when query

Tags: java, openjpa

Entity Class

```
@Id
@Column(length=3)
private String BankID;
```

DAO Class

```
String sSQL = "SELECT x FROM Bank x WHERE x.BankID =?1 ";
Query aQuery = m_aEntityManager.createQuery(sSQL);
aQuery.setParameter(1, sBankID);
```

If I pass '001' to sBankID, everything is OK. 
But if I pass '0001' to sBankID, OpenJPA just throw PersistenceException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null

Is there anyway just to set OpenJPA turn off column lenth validation?(if I don't want modify any eneity and dao source codes)

DB2 9, OpenJPA 1.2

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway just to set OpenJPA turn off column lenth
>   validation?(if I don't want modify any eneity and dao source codes)...
>   DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null

This exception is coming from DB2 and OpenJPA is merely exposing the problem as a PersistenceException. You will need to pass in proper length data to get the exception to go away... or modify your table definition.